# Embedding binary data into an executable using LLVM tools

Tags: freebsd, linker, llvm

In the past I have embedded resource files (images) into programs by first converting them to `.o` files using the GNU linker. For example:

```
ld -r -b binary -o file.o file.svg
```

Starting with FreeBSD 12, the default linker has changed from GNU's to LLVM's. Although the linker appears to understand the command line options, it results in an error. For example:

```
ld -r -b binary -o file.o file.svg
ld: error: target emulation unknown: -m or at least one .o file required
```

Also tried using the command line options from the [ld.lld(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ld) manual page:

```
ld --relocatable --format=binary -o file.o file.svg
ld: error: target emulation unknown: -m or at least one .o file required
```

Am I using the correct tool? Do I need to specify a value for the `-m` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to add `-z noexecstack` (This was added for ELF binaries as well in [LLD 7.0.0](https://releases.llvm.org/7.0.0/tools/lld/docs/ReleaseNotes.html)). The default is to have an executable stack region which is vulnerable to [exploitation via stack memory](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/ExecutableStacks). Your binary image does not have an executable stack and I believe that is why it fails. The error throws you off as it asks you to tell what target emulation to use for your stack (which you do not have).

[David Herrmann](https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/linking-binary-data/) did all the hard work and have found a cross platform solution which covers:

- GNU-ld
- GNU-gold
- GNU-libtool
- work with cross-compiling
- work with LLVM
- do not require any external non-standard tools

The magic invocation is then:

```
$(LD) -r -o "src/mydata.bin.o" -z noexecstack --format=binary "src/mydata.bin"
```

And most often you want that binary segment to be read-only:

```
$(OBJCOPY) --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents "src/mydata.bin.o"
```

### UPDATE:

I could not test as my system was:

```
$ uname -r
11.2-STABLE
$ ld -V
GNU ld 2.17.50 [FreeBSD] 2007-07-03
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64_fbsd
   elf_i386_fbsd
```

I spun up a VM with FreeBSD 12.0 to test this out and found this:

```
$ uname -r
12.0-RELEASE
$ ld -V
LLD 6.0.1 (FreeBSD 335540-1200005) (compatible with GNU linkers)
```

The `-z noexecstack` was only added in 7.0.0 and it is not listed in the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ld&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) for 6.0.1. More annoyingly specifying unsupported values for `-z` does not trigger an error!

I have not upgraded to LLVM 7 to test if that does the trick. @Richard Smith found a proper solution himself by specifying the emulation with `-m` in another answer. That route would be so much easier if LLD listed supported emulations with `-V`.

If you use the `file` command on `file.o` you will see it identifies as SYSV ELF. This might be good enough for you. But if you want the exact samme as the system then use `elf_amd64_fbsd` which is an [alias](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D7837) for `elf_x86_64_fbsd`. Annoyingly `ld -V` does not output supported emulations with LLD as GNU ld does.

```
$ file /bin/cat
/bin/cat: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), dynamically linked, interpreter /libexec/ld-elf.so.1, for FreeBSD 12.0 (1200086), FreeBSD-style, stripped
$ ld -r -b binary -m elf_amd64 -o data.o data.bin
$ file data.o
data.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
$ ld -r -b binary -m elf_amd64_fbsd -o data.o data.bin
$ file data.o
data.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), not stripped
```

`elf_amd64_fbsd` is an alias for `elf_x86_64_fbsd` (see [D7837](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D7837) and [D24356](https://reviews.llvm.org/D24356)). Hopefully LLD will add the emulations to the `-V` output.

Comment: I tried adding the `-z noexecstack` option, but I get the same error message. As you say, it's not a useful error message, you get the same error message if you type `ld` with no parameters at all!

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the source, the correct *target emulation* for my platform is **elf_amd64**. So the conversion from binary to object file works using:

```
ld -r -b binary -m elf_amd64 -o file.o file.svg
```

Comment: If you use the `file` command on `file.o` you will see it identifies as SYSV ELF. This might be good enough for you. But if you want the exact samme as the system then use `elf_amd64_fbsd` which is an [alias](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D7837) for `elf_x86_64_fbsd`. Annoyingly `ld -V` does not output supported emulations as GNU ld does.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really worth the trouble? That wasn't portable in the first place.

You should better convert your .svg to a C char array; Example:

```
$ cat Makefile
.SUFFIXES: .svg
.svg.c:
        od -tx1 $< | sed 's/ /,0x/g;s/[^,]*//;1s/,/char $*[]={/;$$s/$$/};/' > $@

$ make file.o
od -tx1 file.svg | sed 's/ /,0x/g;s/[^,]*//;1s/,/char file[]={/;$s/$/};/' > file.c
cc    -c -o file.o file.c
rm file.c
```

Of course, you can set the name of the array to something different / more robust (eg. `char $(subst /,_,$*)[] = ...` instead of `char $*[] = ...` with GNU make). Also, you could build an ad-hoc `bin2c` converter written in C instead of that horrible od+sed combo.

Comment: I like the idea of a bin2c converter

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer a simplistic tool called [res_embed](https://github.com/dmikushin/res_embed). It has a similar scope, but not based on LLVM. It basically uses NASM or gas to embed the binary through the assembly files. It's wrapped into a high-level CMake interface:

```
add_executable(res_example "example.cpp")
res_embed(TARGET res_example NAME "my_cool_image" PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.svg)
```

Then you can use the embedded resource in your program like this:

```
#include "res_embed.h"

#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%s", res::embed::get("my_cool_image"));
    return 0;
}
```

Provided that gas is available on the most of platforms, this solution is portable. It also supports MSVC in Windows via NASM. And it is similar to your LLD approach in the following aspect: res_embed avoids consequences of attempting to embed a resource as a C array, which dramatically slows down compilation in case of a huge resource for no good reason.